# Jacoco coverage report of JUnit tests for a Gradle multiproject

Tags: gradle, junit, spring-boot

I am having difficulty combining Jacoco coverage report for a Gradle multi-project. For simplicity, I have created a simplified version that is structured as follows. I have the example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ChrisZhong/gradle-jacoco-multiproject).

```
+ root
  + common-a
  + common-b
  + project-a
  + project-b
```

The `root`, `project-a`, and `project-b` are Spring Boot applications. For some context, a project is meant to be a micro-service. Thus, the root project is simply running all micro-services in one process.

Not all projects have unit and/or integration tests. `common-a` subproject does not have any tests; `common-b`, `project-a`, and `project-b` projects have unit and integration tests; the `root` project has only integration tests.

The Jacoco coverage reports for subprojects are correct. It is able to combine both unit and integration tests into one cohesive report. However, the `root` project does not produce the cohesive report correctly.

I have tried a number of solutions with any success. Most of the solutions I found assume that the `root` project is simply a logical container and only the subprojects has test code. The results of the solutions I tried fall into one of the following three categories.

1. No Jacoco report generated at all; the `build/reports/jacoco` directory is missing
2. Partial Jacoco report for only sources in `root` project
3. Full Jacoco coverage report for `root` and subproject but 0% coverage; it is supposed to be 100% coverage

The following is the current `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
    }
}
// settings for all projects
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    group 'io.github.chriszhong'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:2.0.5.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        integrationTest {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output

            java {
                srcDir 'src/test-integration/java'
            }

            resources {
                srcDir 'src/test-integration/resources'
            }
        }
    }

    configurations {
        integrationTestCompile {
            extendsFrom testCompile
        }
        integrationTestRuntime {
            extendsFrom testRuntime
        }
    }

    idea {
        module {
            testSourceDirs += sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs
            testSourceDirs += sourceSets.integrationTest.resources.srcDirs
        }
    }

    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        check {
            dependsOn integrationTest
        }
        testClassesDir sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    task testReport(type: TestReport) {
        dependsOn check
        destinationDir file("${reporting.baseDir}/unified/html")
        reportOn test, integrationTest
    }

    task jacocoMerge(type: JacocoMerge) {
        dependsOn check
        executionData test, integrationTest
        // temporary hack to fix a bug requiring that there be at least one test case in each source set for coverage data to be generated;
        // it should be if there is at least one test case in any of the source sets
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll({ it.exists() }))
    }

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        reports {
            html {
                destination file("${reporting.baseDir}/${task.name}/html")
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {
        dependsOn jacocoMerge
        executionData jacocoMerge.destinationFile
        // temporary hack to fix a bug requiring that there be at least one test case in each source set for coverage data to be generated;
        // it should be if there is at least one test case in any of the source sets
//        executionData = files(executionData.findAll({ it.exists() }))
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile project(':project-a')
    compile project(':project-b')

    testCompile 'junit:junit'

    integrationTestCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

testReport {
    dependsOn check, subprojects.testReport
    reportOn test, integrationTest, subprojects.test, subprojects.integrationTest
}

jacocoMerge {
    dependsOn check, subprojects.jacocoMerge
    executionData test, integrationTest, subprojects.jacocoMerge.destinationFile
    // temporary hack to fix a bug requiring that there be at least one test case in each source set for coverage data to be generated;
    // it should be if there is at least one test case in any of the source sets
    executionData = files(executionData.findAll({ it.exists() }))
}

//jacocoTestReport {
//    dependsOn jacocoMerge
//    executionData test, integrationTest, subprojects.test, subprojects.integrationTest
//    executionData jacocoMerge.destinationFile
    // temporary hack to fix a bug requiring that there be at least one test case in each source set for coverage data to be generated;
    // it should be if there is at least one test case in any of the source sets
//    executionData = files(executionData.findAll({ it.exists() }))
//    sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs, subprojects.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)
//    classDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir, subprojects.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
//}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion '2.14'
    distributionUrl "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${gradleVersion}-all.zip"
}
```

I have been banging my head at this problem for the past week and is at my wits end. I greatly appreciate any help I can get in resolving this problem.